# Buying a handgun at age 18 in Virginia

Tags: regulations, firearms, virginia

Can a person buy a handgun and handgun ammo legally at 18 from a private sale in Virginia?

Answer (score 1):

### Possibly not

The minimum age for a purchase in Virginia of a handgun (pistol) is 21. Long guns may be purchased at 18. This is clearly the age for obtaining a concealed carry permit, and for purchases from a licensed dealer or at a gun show.

However, a purely private sale may be an exception, Virginia law permits possession by persons 18 and over, provided the gun is openly carried, and does not have a clear and absolute age limit on purchase beyond federal rules as far as I can find.

#### Sources

Virginal law [§ 18.2-308.02](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter7/section18.2-308.02/) as now in effect provides that:

> A. Any person 21 years of age or older may apply in writing to the clerk of the circuit court of the county or city in which he resides, or if he is a member of the United States Armed Forces and stationed outside the Commonwealth, the county or city in which he is domiciled, for a five-year permit to carry a concealed handgun. ...

Under [VA § 18.2-308.7](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/18.2-308.7/) possession of a handgun is unlawful for persons under 18. Under [VA § 18.2-308.2:1.](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter7/section18.2-308.2:1/) private sales to persons prohibited from possession under § 18.2-308.7 (or any of several other sections, none of which seem to apply to the question) is unlawful.

Under [VA § 18.2-308.2:5.](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter7/section18.2-308.2:5/) a background check, or "a determination from the Department of State Police that the purchaser is not prohibited under state or federal law from possessing a firearm". This applies to all sales, even private sales.

[VA § 18.2-308.7](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter7/section18.2-308.7/) prohibits possession of an handgun or an "assault weapon" by anyone under 18, but does not mention purchase

[This page from Showmasters Gun Shows](https://www.showmastersgunshows.com/va-purchase-requirements.html) says:

> A person must be at least 18 years of age to purchase a rifle or shotgun from a licensed firearms dealer. To purchase a handgun from a licensed firearms dealer, you must be at least 21 years of age, pursuant to federal law.
>
> ...
>
> Virginia law does not address age requirements for the purchase of ammunition. Federal law requires an individual to be at least 21 years of age to purchase handgun ammunition, and at least 18 years old to purchase rifle or shotgun ammunition​​

> ...
>
> To privately sell a firearm, it is recommended that you safeguard information pertaining to the transaction such as the date the firearm was sold, the complete name and address of the buyer, and the make, model, and serial number of the firearm. The seller and buyer of a handgun must be a resident of the state in which the transfer occurs.  Should the firearm ever be located at a crime scene, trace of the firearm will determine the licensed dealer who last sold the firearm and will identify the last buyer of the firearm. To have your name removed from this process, you may consider placing your firearm on consignment with a licensed dealer. This will also ensure that the firearm is transferred only to a lawfully eligible individual.

The Virginia State Police ["Firearms Purchase Eligibility Test"](https://www.vsp.virginia.gov/Firearms_PurchaseEligibility.shtm) does not mention any minimum age.

The Federal [Omnibus Crime Control and Safe Streets Act of 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_Crime_Control_and_Safe_Streets_Act_of_1968) prohibits sales of handguns to persons under 21. However [This ATF page](https://www.atf.gov/questions-and-answers/qa/may-individual-between-ages-18-and-21-years-age-acquire-handgun-unlicensed) says that this restriction does not apply to private sales by persons who are not licensed dealers.

The Wikipedia article [Gun laws in Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_laws_in_Virginia) says that:

> Open carry is generally allowed without a permit for people 18 years of age and older.
>
> ...
>
> Proof of age (18+ for long arms, 21+ for pistols) and proof of citizenship (or permanent residence license) are required for the purchase of "assault weapons". "Assault weapons" are defined as a semi-automatic, centerfire, firearm equipped with a folding stock, or equipped at the time with a magazine capable of holding more than 20 rounds, or capable of accommodating a silencer/suppressor.

Answer (score -1):

A resident of Virginia can buy a handgun in Virginia at 18 in a private sale without a background check.  If they are 21+, they need a background check.

https://fredericksburg.com/article_a8a6bbda-31a8-5b28-bbe8-b07e507ada7d.html

Comment: Eh... that judge only said "you can't ban 18-21 from buying guns", not "you can't demand a check". What was deemed illegal is the BGC to return "can't have it" on the basis of age alone.